# How to use a command SCP on a python Program Linux inj a nested connection

Tags: python, ssh, scp

I'm trying to create a python script that can copy files host inside another host and place it in my local folder.

So the the setup is as follow Localhost -> HOST_1 -> HOST_2. So what I want is to copy files from HOST_2 (that is connected to HOST_1) and put it in localhost.

Which scp command can I use to perform that if HOST_1 ip address is '172.254.2.20' and HOST_2 ip address is '196.20.0.2' and I want to copy a file that is '/var/tmp/my.log' to my localhost '/home/user1/my.log'

Comment: In your python script you can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to call the `scp` command

Comment: yes, that is what I pretend to do but what is the exactly command to do that? from localhost to host is quite easy to copy but how should I do in case I have a nested connection... I mean localhost -> HOST_1 -> HOST_2 (I want to copy files directly from HOST_2 to localhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to fix it:

```
sshpass -p password_C scp -oProxyCommand="sshpass -p password_B f'ssh -W %h:%p HOST_B@HOST_B_IP" HOST_C_USER@HOST_C_IP:/source/folder destination_folder_in_A
```